# Jenkins build parameter where user adds list values

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like my Jenkins job to run against many servers, but I do NOT want them to be predefined.

How can I create a Parameterized Jenkins Job that allows whoever is using it to 'dynamically add' a server list to the build params?

For example:

```
Enter applicable hosts:
10.0.0.27 [ + ]
```

When the + is pressed, another empty row is created, and the user can add another IP address. It doesn't have to exactly be like this (with the + button), but any suggestions on accomplishing the same idea would be amazing.

Ideally I want to do this within a Jenkinsfile. Does anyone have any advice on how to approach this, or which plugin to look into?

Thanks!
Dragan

Comment: By dynamically add do you mean that job should not have predefined list of servers or do you mean that Jenkins should not have a list of servers?
I can share an answer for the first scenario i.e. Jenkins have the list of servers. A user, at the time of running a job can add the servers to that job from the list available with Jenkins.

Comment: What I mean is Jenkins does NOT have a predefined list. The user creates the list when clicking "Build With Parameters"